# How to implement tree command in bash/shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I tried to implement in bash some code which output would be similar to the "tree" command in the terminal.

Here it is:

```
listContent() {
    local file
    for file in "$1"/*; do
        if [ -d $file ]; then
            countSpaces $file
            echo $?"Directory: $file"
            listContent "$file"
        elif [ -f $file ]; then
            countSpaces $file
            echo $?"File: $file"
        fi
    done
}

countSpaces() {
    local space="   "
    for (( i=0; i<${#$1}; i++ )); do
        if [ ${file:$i:1} = "/" ]; then
        space = space + space
        return space
    done
}

listContent "$1"
```

Running the script I give: ./scriptName.sh  directoryName
where scriptName is my script and directoryName is the argument which is the name of the directory from which the code should start.

I would like to see the output like this:

```
Directory: Bash/Test1Dir
    File: Bash/Test1Dir/Test1Doc.txt
Directory: Bash/Test2Dir
    Directory: Bash/Test2Dir/InsideTest2DirDir
        File: Bash/Test2Dir/insideTest2DirDoc.txt
File: Bash/test.sh
```

But I have some troubles in completing this code. Could someone help me figure it out why it isn't working and what should I change?

Will be grateful.

Comment: http://shellcheck.net/ is your friend. It'll explicitly explain what's wrong with `space = space + space`, for example. (`return space` shellcheck might not explain -- short form is that `return` is only used for exit status -- short integers; `$?` can never be a non-numeric value, so you can't use it for strings).

Comment: Also, you're missing a bunch of mandatory quotes, and shellcheck will catch that too.

Comment: Beyond that, though -- A good StackOverflow question centers on a *specific problem*; ie. "why does this one line do X, not Y, after I set variable A to N and B to M?", as opposed to something broad like "why doesn't my program work?". If you haven't narrowed your question down to a place where you have a specific question about the language or runtime, you arguably have more debugging to do before you have a question ready to ask on this site.

Comment: Thank you for response. I appreciate that. I just started with bash and this is new syntax for me, so I thought someone could give me a tip or lead. But you are right. The question is not directed to specific problem, I am just asking for code review. Will note that for future.

Comment: BTW, as a much shorter way to generate a variable containing a number of spaces depending on the number of slashes in a path, consider `slashes=${file//[^\/]/}; spaces=${slashes//\//"    "}` -- see http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe for discussion of why/how it works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A correct and efficient implementation might look like:

```
listContent() {
  local dir=${1:-.} whitespacePrefix=$2 file
  for file in "$dir"/*; do
    [ -e "$file" ] || [ -L "$file" ] || continue
    if [ -d "$file" ]; then
      printf '%sDirectory %q\n' "$whitespacePrefix" "${file##*/}"
      listContent "$file" "${whitespacePrefix}    "
    else
      printf '%sFile %q\n' "$whitespacePrefix" "${file##*/}"
    fi
  done
}
```

Note:

- Instead of counting spaces, we use the call stack to track the amount of whitespace, appending on each recursive call. This avoids needing to count the number of `/`s in each name.
- We quote *all* parameter expansions, except in one of the limited number of contexts where string-splitting and glob expansions are implicitly avoided.
- We avoid attempts to use `$?` for anything other than its intended purpose of tracking numeric exit status.
- We use `printf %q` whenever uncontrolled data (such as a filename) is present, to ensure that even malicious names (containing newlines, cursor-control characters, etc) are printed unambiguously.

Answer (score 0):

if you want a visual representation without the `Directory` and `File` leaders, then the following is a simple one-liner (wrapped in a shell function).

```bash
treef() (
    [ -d "$1" ] && { dir="$1"; shift; } || dir='.'
    find "$dir" "$@" | sed -e 's@/@|@g;s/^\.|//;s/[^|][^|]*|/ |/g;/^[. |]*$/d'
)
```